Как уменьшить пинг на своём сайте
Я создал своё api и запустил его на удалённом сервере, через https (использую nginx-1.27.2). Но апи отвечает очень медлено, если я обращаюсь к нему, скажем, в 100 потоках одновременно, время пинга вырастает до 50 секунд. В одном потоке обычно пинг 10-15 мс, но иногда бывают просадки до 3-4 секунд.
Программа на сервере выглядит так:
from quart import Quart, request, jsonify
app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
async def home_api():
    data = await request.get_json()
    return jsonify({"status": "Good"}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

Пробовал Flask и Quart, с асинхронностью и без, post и get запросы. Менял конфиги nginx по подсказкам ChatGPT. Проблема остаётся.
Сервер мощный, с двумя процессорами intel(r) xeon(r) cpu e5-2690 v4 @ 2.60ghz. Всего 28 ядер. Интернет на обоих компьютерах гигабит, оптоволокно, пинг 1 мс. Из-за чего могут быть задержки и как сделать стабильный пинг на укровне 10-15мс?
Конфигурация nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    server_name your_domain.com www.your_domain.com;
    worker_connections 2048;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  # Перенаправление с HTTP на HTTPS
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name your_domain.com www.your_domain.com;
    client_max_body_size 100M; 
    worker_connections 2048;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        # Ваши настройки
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Клиентская программа выглядит примерно так:
def ping():
    global D
    t1 = time.time()
    i = D.pop()
    data =  {"request":str(i), "limit": 300}
    url = 'https://.../api'
    response = requests.get(url, json=data)
    return(time.time()-t1)

def ping_multiple_requests(num_requests):
    times = []
    for _ in range(num_requests):
        times.append(ping())
    return times

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(ping_multiple_requests, requests_per_thread) for _ in range(num_threads)]
    for future in futures:
        all_times.extend(future.result())


Ну, очевидный вопрос - запросы с nginx напрямую идут на flask/quart или через веб-сервер (gunicorn/hypercorn)? Если через них - как минимум укажите, сколько воркеров запускаете.

Насколько я помню, flask однопоточный. Попробуйте перейти на fastapi.

@insolor
Перенаправление с порта 80 идёт. Я добавил в вопрос конфигурацию

@Максим вы не ответили на вопрос. gunicorn/hypercorn используется, или тупо однопоточно flask/quart запускаете?

@CrazyElf я так же пробовал Quart, он многопоточный. fastapi сейчас проверю.

@CrazyElf, вот как раз чтобы не однопоточно было, нужно использовать вебсервер. Для неасинхронных  фреймворков (flask, django) - это gunicorn, для асинхронных, того же fastapi - uvicorn, для quart нагуглил hypercorn. fastapi тоже без вебсервера не стоит запускать, он сам по себе тоже однопоточный.

@insolor Я использовал waitress для многопоточности. Сейчас попробую gunicorn и hypercorn

В вопросе следовало бы привести код тестирования. Если отправляется 100 запросов и задержка растет - то это проблема, а если каждый из 100 потоков бомбардирует сервер непрерывной чередой запросов, то не удивительно, что задержка будет расти. Для такого нагрузочного тестирования придется использовать либо много машин, либо множество сетевых интерфейсов, чтобы пул клиентских портов не вычерпывать моментально.

@user7860670
Мне нужно что бы сервер мог выдерживать тысячи запросов в секунду, особенно учитывая, что ответ считается мгновенно. Но проблема в том что даже в одном потоке бывают просадки до 2-3 секунд на ответ. Да, каждый из потоков обращается к серверу непрерывно, но это не запредельная нагрузка и он должен с таким справляться.
Я проверил fastapi. Никаких изменений.

Сам производитель fastAPI что-то хитрое вообще наворотил: "Docker image with Uvicorn managed by Gunicorn for high-performance FastAPI web applications in Python with performance auto-tuning." https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker?tab=readme-ov-file

¿И сколько там requests_per_thread?

А что такое global D у вас и не лочит ли GIL эту вашу D? А то может вы просто меряете блокировки GIL, а не реальное время запросов? Попробуйте ради интереса начинать мерить время после i = D.pop(), а не до.

@user7860670
100 потоков каждый делает по 100 запросов подряд. Хотя уже после 10-15 запросов начинаются вылеты с пропажей соединения.

@CrazyElf Просто set() с тестовой выборкой запросов. Заменял на random.randint() и никаких изменений это не дало.

@Максим Ну попробуйте таки строки местами переставить. И почитайте уже про GIL. Если хотите родные питоновские коллекции использовать многопоточно, то будьте готовы к тормозам из-за GIL. Нужно использовать специальные коллекции для многопоточного доступа к данным из multiprocessing. Но и то я не уверен, что не упрётесь в GIL. Лучше раздавайте аргументы функциям сразу когда плодите потоки. Так можно. Чтобы потоки никак не пересекались между собой, обращаясь к одним и тем же общим данным. Никаких global! Никакого обращения к внешним для функции переменным! Тогда GIL не страшен.

Может быть здесь и не в этом дело, конечно. Но нужно иметь в виду.

@CrazyElf, в uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker в шапке написано, что This Docker image is now deprecated, и теперь предлагается использовать uvicorn с ключом --workers и Kubernetes. Я смотрел доклад из 2021 года про fastapi, там рассказывалось, что есть какие-то проблемы с голым uvicorn, и нужно его использовать в связке с gunicorn (ссылка с таймкодом), но видимо с тех пор что-то допилили или починили.

@insolor Картина всё больше проясняется )  Я и удивился - зачем они такое наворотили, без лишней нужды тянуть в один проект несколько конкурирующих фреймворков было как-то странно. Теперь понятно.
